# Html5 native datepicker, on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a itemlist in my mobile application with search field and date field.
But i'm not possible to trigger my function when i change the date with HTML5's native datepicker on iOS.

I have tried jq change() function and on.('input') but its not seems to work.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved

onBlur gets trigged on iOS (Safari, iCab)

**Test 1**

```
<script>
function test(test) {
    alert("trigged");
}
</script>
<input type="date" onblur="test()" />
```

**Test 2**

```
jQuery("input[name=date]").blur(function() { alert("hi"); });
```